# Handling user choice with conditional logic in Jinja template (caesar cipher Django web app)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, conditional-statements, jinja2

I’m writing a Django web app which basically presents the web visitor with the option to encrypt / decrypt a message using a very rudimentary caesar cipher. I got the encryption function to work but when I tried to implement conditional logic in my template to handle the user’s initial choice on the landing page (the option to encrypt or decrypt), Django is not serving the client the option. I’m not sure why.

I’m expecting Django to give the web visitor this choice on the landing page:

> Would you like to encrypt a plaintext message? Or would you like to decrypt a scrambled message?

(...where each question is a hyperlink  that takes the visitor to a page to enter their message).

When the web visitor lands on the page, neither option is showing. Django just serves a blank template.

Here is a temporary mirror of my dev server: https://d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io

Here is my [views.py](https://github.com/enoren5/Django_caesar/blob/conditional-template-logic/landings/views.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import string

def caesar(request):
    # Courtesy of Real Python: https://realpython.com/python-practice-problems/
    if 'encrypt' in request.GET:
        plain_text = request.GET['original_entry']
        shift_num = request.GET['shift_num']
        shift_num = int(shift_num)
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        mask = letters[shift_num:] + letters[:shift_num]
        trantab = str.maketrans(letters, mask)
        output_text = plain_text.translate(trantab)
        context = {'select_option': False, 'output_text': output_text, 'original_entry': plain_text, 'conv_decrypt': False, 'conv_encrypt': True}
        return render(request, 'landings/home.html', context)
    
    elif 'decrypt' in request.GET:
        plain_text = request.GET['original_entry']
        shift_num = request.GET['shift_num']
        shift_num = -int(shift_num)
        letters = string.ascii_lowercase
        mask = letters[shift_num:] + letters[:shift_num]
        trantab = str.maketrans(letters, mask)
        output_text = plain_text.translate(trantab)
        context = {'select_option': False, 'output_text': output_text, 'original_entry': plain_text, 'conv_decrypt': True, 'conv_encrypt': False}
        return render(request, 'landings/home.html', context)
    
    elif 'conversion' in request.GET:
        conversion = request.GET['conversion']
        if conversion == 'encrypt':
            context = {'select_option': False, 'result_encrypt': True, 'result_decrypt': False, 'conv_decrypt': True, 'conv_encrypt': False, 'conv_decrypt': False, 'conv_encrypt': True}
            return render(request, 'landings/home.html', context)
        elif conversion == 'decrypt':
            context = {'select_option': False, 'result_encrypt': False, 'result_decrypt': True}
            return render(request, 'landings/home.html', context)
    
    return render(request, 'landings/home.html')
```

Here is the template ([home.html](https://github.com/enoren5/Django_caesar/blob/conditional-template-logic/templates/landings/home.html)) I am working with:

```
{% block content %}   

   <br>
   <center>
  
   <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
   {% if select_option %}
   <h3>Would you like to <a href="{% url 'caesar' %}?conversion=encrypt">encrypt</a> a plaintext message?</h3>

   <h3>Or would you like <a href="{% url 'caesar' %}?conversion=decrypt">to decrypt</a> a scrambled message?</h3>
   {% elif conv_encrypt %}
   <form action="{% url 'caesar' %}" >
       Enter the text you wish to scramble here:
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="original_entry" />
       <br />
       Enter your key:
       <br>
       <input type="number" name="shift_num" />
       <br />
       <input type="submit" value="Encrypt!" />
     </form>
   </form>
   {% elif conv_decrypt %}
   <form action="{% url 'caesar' %}" >
       Enter the text you wish to scramble here:
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="original_entry" />
       <br />
       Enter your key:
       <br>
       <input type="number" name="shift_num" />
       <br />
       <input type="submit" value="Decrypt!" />
     </form>
   {% elif result_encrypt %}
  
   <h3>Here is your message encrypted:</h3>

   <div class="field"> {{ output_text }} </div>

   <br>
   <a href="{% url 'caesar' %}"><div class="field"> <strong> Again? Click here! </strong> </div> </a>

 {% elif result_decrypt %}
   <h3>Here is your message decrypted:</h3>
  
   <div class="field"> {{ output_text }} </div>
 
   <br>
   <a href="{% url 'caesar' %}"><div class="field"> <strong> Again? Click here! </strong> </div> </a>

 {% endif %}
```

Here is [the full source code](https://github.com/enoren5/Django_caesar/tree/conditional-template-logic) on my full GitHub repo with a reference to my current working branch.

What I have tried so far:

- I’ve tried swapping different truth values in my views.py. For example, I tried switching the key-value pair  `'select_option': False,` from False to True. I tried different combinations in the four different positions in the views.py.`
- My cipher algorithm is based on [Jim Anderson’s practice problem](https://realpython.com/python-practice-problems/) on Real Python.
- There is no traceback for me to work with so I don’t have any search terms to look up on Google.

My local development environment is running Python 3.9.1 on a Linux system. Here is the output of  `$ pip freeze`:

```
asgiref==3.3.1 
Django==3.1.5 
Pillow==8.1.0 
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.4.1 
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

I am basing this caesar cipher web app on a prior web app for a separate Django project called [CC_Redact](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3) which successfully serves the web visitor a choice either to convert miles to kilometres or kilometres to miles ([template](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/master/templates/alls/landings.html), [views.py](https://github.com/enoren5/CC_Redact_Iter3/blob/master/converters/views.py)). It functions and behaves as intended. I’m trying to emulate that working feature.

Comment: first check `print( request.GET )` - maybe you don't have `encrypt`, `decrypt` , `conversion` in `request.GET` and then it executes `return render(request, 'landings/home.html')` without `select_option`,  `conv_encrypt`,  `conv_decrypt` and you get empty page. As for me you have too much `if/elif` but you don't have `else` which could display something when you don't have other variables.

Comment: as for me all your problem is that you have to run url with arguments to see anything - ie. https://d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?conversion=encrypt - and if you run without any argument then you see nothing. You don't have code which displays anything when there is no options. It could display links to page with arguments ie. https://d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?conversion=encrypt https://d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?conversion=decrypt OR you should use option `{'select_option': True}` in last `return` - `return render(request, 'landings/home.html', {'select_option': True})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me all your problem is that you have to run `url` with arguments to see anything

```
d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?conversion=encrypt 
d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?conversion=decrypt

d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?encrypt&original_entry=...&shift_num=...
d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io/?decrypt&original_entry=...&shift_num=...
```

and when you run it without arguments

```
d0d342ea4934.ngrok.io
```

then it runs last `return`

```
return render(request, 'landings/home.html')
```

which doesn't have context `{'select_option': True, ...}` so your `template` display nothing.

In last `return` you should have at least

```
return render(request, 'landings/home.html', {'select_option': True})
```

to display

```
Would you like to encrypt a plaintext message? 
Or would you like to decrypt a scrambled message?
```

Comment: Eureka! Thank you, furas! Yes, adding `{'select_option': True}` to the final return operation (the last line) displays "Would you like to encrypt a plaintext message? Or would you like to decrypt a scrambled message?". Some of the other Truthy values still need tweaking but you have resolved my main question. Thanks! :)